# Why isn't phone7 triggering multiple mouse events for Path obects?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a Windows Phone 7 application that needs to raise multiple mouse up events simultaneously. I'm using the `Path` control to play a sound file and I need 2 different files to play if the person presses the 2 path objects simultaneously (like a piano application).

How do I handle 2 simultaneous mouse presses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The platform does support multi-touch like this, but because of the history of the APIs from Silverlight on the desktop there is effectively only one "mouse" on WP7 for it to be "up". That means you can't use a "mouse" in the way you describe.

If you want to detect this kind of thing you need to think in terms of the touch points the phone can detect.

See MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607287%28VS.96%29.aspx) for information on touch input support - however it sounds like you'd need something lower level such as [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.touch%28v=VS.96%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `GestureListener` in the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com) for this. Use the `PinchDelta` event to get multiple touch coordinates. As far as I can see, it only supports two-fingers.

```
private void GestureListener_PinchDelta(object sender, PinchGestureEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.GetPosition(LayoutRoot, 0));
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.GetPosition(LayoutRoot, 1));
```

So if you need more, you might have to implement a full input event decoding yourself, or look for a better suited library. Consider looking at the source for the `GestureListener` as well.

Comment: I think the problem with this approach would be targeting more than a single UIElement (Path in this case) at a time.

Comment: True. Oh well, at least it's listed as a option.